# Effecting a Shift of an FCOLORBOX within a Simple Lettrine

Tags: pdftex, vertical, lettrine, colorbox

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{type1cm,lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\large

\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.4,lraise=.15,nindent=.80em,findent=.20em]{\fboxsep10pt\fboxrule15pt\fcolorbox{red}{yellow!75!brown}{\color{red}I}}{would} like to shift (vertically, horizontally) the yellow box containing the letter within the outer red box.
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: How may I horizontally (and vertically) effect a shift of the `fcolorbox` containing the letter within the outer red box?

**EDIT:** Is it possible to do this without redefining the fcolorbox?

I compile the code with `pdflatex`.

Thank you.

Comment: @Simon Dispa O.k. Fair enough.

Comment: I upvote questions when I learn something new in the process of answering. +1 :)

Comment: @Simon Dispa And I learned something new with `longbox`. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\fcolorbox` will draw a box with the same inner padding and border width in all directions.

The `longbox` allows you to separately set the top, bottom left and right widths of the padding and border. It is then possible to move the inner yellow box inside the outer red box by manipulating these parameters.

Two lengths, `\xshift` and `\yshift`, were defined using the lower-left-corner of the outer red box as the origin.

The original `\fcolorbox` has a 15pt border and 10pt padding inside. The figure shows that the `longbox` faithfully reproduces it.

[image: a]

Obviously the maximum values for shifts are, in this example, 25pt, to keep the yellow box within the red box.

The second figure shows three examples. `depth=1` was added  to accommodate a fourth line.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{longfbox}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\newlength{\yshift} 
\newlength{\xshift} 

\usepackage{type1cm,lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\begin{document}
    
\thispagestyle{empty}
\large

\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.4,lraise=.4,nindent=.80em,findent=.20em, depth=1 ]{\fboxsep10pt\fboxrule15pt\fcolorbox{red}{yellow!75!brown}{\color{red}I}}{would} like to shift (vertically, horizontally) the yellow box containing the letter within the outer red box. \emph{With a text more the three lines  lraise must be changed or depth added.}

\bigskip
    
\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.4,lraise=.4,nindent=.80em,findent=.20em, depth=1]{%
    \lfbox[border-top-width=15pt,
    border-bottom-width=15pt,
    border-left-width=15pt,
    border-right-width=15pt,
    padding-right=10pt,
    padding-left=10pt,
    padding-top=10pt,   
    padding-bottom=10pt,    
    border-color=red,background-color= yellow!75!brown,]{\color{red}I}}{would} like to shift (vertically, horizontally) the yellow box containing the letter within the outer red box. (done with \textbf{longfbox})    

\newpage

\setlength{\yshift}{0pt}    % bottom left corner
\setlength{\xshift}{0pt}
\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.4,lraise=.4,nindent=.80em,findent=.20em, depth=1]{%
    \lfbox[border-top-width=\dimexpr 25pt- \yshift,
    border-bottom-width=\yshift,
    border-left-width=\xshift,
    border-right-width=\dimexpr 25pt- \xshift,
    padding-right=10pt,
    padding-left=10pt,
    padding-top=10pt,   
    padding-bottom=10pt,    
    border-color=red,background-color= yellow!75!brown,]{\color{red}I}}{would} like to shift (vertically, horizontally) the yellow box containing the letter within the outer red box. (done with \textbf{longfbox} X = 0pt, Y = 0pt))

\vspace{25pt}

\setlength{\yshift}{4pt}    
\setlength{\xshift}{10pt}   
\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.4,lraise=.4,nindent=.80em,findent=.20em, depth=1]{%
    \lfbox[border-top-width=\dimexpr 25pt- \yshift,
    border-bottom-width=\yshift,
    border-left-width=\xshift,
    border-right-width=\dimexpr 25pt- \xshift,
    padding-right=10pt,
    padding-left=10pt,
    padding-top=10pt,   
    padding-bottom=10pt,    
    border-color=red,background-color= yellow!75!brown,]{\color{red}I}}{would} like to shift (vertically, horizontally) the yellow box containing the letter within the outer red box.
 (done with \textbf{longfbox}; X = 10pt, Y = 4pt)

\vspace{15pt}

\setlength{\yshift}{25pt}   % top right corner
\setlength{\xshift}{25pt}   
\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.4,lraise=.4,nindent=.80em,findent=.20em, depth=1]{%
    \lfbox[border-top-width=\dimexpr 25pt- \yshift,
    border-bottom-width=\yshift,
    border-left-width=\xshift,
    border-right-width=\dimexpr 25pt- \xshift,
    padding-right=10pt,
    padding-left=10pt,
    padding-top=10pt,   
    padding-bottom=10pt,    
    border-color=red,background-color= yellow!75!brown,]{\color{red}I}}{would} like to shift (vertically, horizontally) the yellow box containing the letter within the outer red box. 
(done with \textbf{longfbox}; X = 25pt, Y =  25pt)  
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but would you be able to post some working code which effects a vertical and a horizontal shift of the yellow box---keeping the box entirely within the red frame? i.e., a red border around  the entire yellow box of thickness >= 0? Many thanks.

Comment: @mlchristians Sorry! I got distracted by a call and forgot. Now the code is in place.

Comment: No problem. Thanks again.